# Can't install gnome shell extensions

Tags: opensuse, gnome-shell

Just did a fairly minimal install of OpenSUSE 13.1, including `gnome-shell` 3.10.1. [Long frustrated rant deleted] I can't get GNOME shell extensions to work at all.

Initially when I went to the extensions website, I couldn't install anything. Eventually I discovered the secret, undocumented `gnome-shell-browser-plugin` package. Having installed that, the little on/off switch now appears on the website. However, when I switch it to On, nothing happens. And if I navigate off the page and back again, it's gone back to Off.

Who do I have to murder to make this actually work again?

Comment: Ah. Yet another feather in gnome-shell's cap!

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @JeroenBollen I haven't managed to fix it yet. I _did_, however, discover that if you can find a suitable download site, you can just manually copy the files to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. It's hardly "convenient", though.